# Intellisense with ES5

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-5

I have been using VSCode for quite a long time and while it's very good, I'm missing intellisense and features that seem to be ES6-only:

- I cannot ctrl+click to go to definition
- I cannot have a preview of the definition

Here is what I am using:

- ES5
- Angular JS

All my files are wrapped into a closure, like:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('foo').factory('bar', ['dep1', function(dep1) {
      dep1.stuff();
    }]);
})();
```

With that in mind, is it possible to have "goto definition" and other nice VSCode stuff working ? If so, how ?

What can I do to be able to simply click ctrl+click on dep1 and have VSCode open the file where dep1 is defined ?

Answer (score 1):

What I can recommend is that you try to install John Papa's extension for Visual Studio Code for Angular 1.x. It is installed directly through VSCode. You can check some examples of how it works [here](https://johnpapa.net/vscode-ng-snippets/). It will offer you code completion and it will automate a lot of tasks you frequently do in Angular, such as creating services, controllers, directives...

[image]

Btw John Papa is the author of the [Angular Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and his way of coding could be called "best-practice" in the world of Angular development.

Comment: Thank you: I'll take a look. Will it offer code completion for Angular builtin files as well as for the files I write too ?

Comment: What do you mean by Angular built in files? Please upvote the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I mean: I think this extension will add completion on angular objects, like: $scope, angular, etc... what if I want autocomplete on my own angular elements as well ? (my controllers, services,..)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get intellisense for javascript/typescript is to install `typings`.

I find that this extension is good with installing typings: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjaminromano.typings-installer

Once you have that installed, you can then launch it (`F1 > Typings Installer: Typings > angular`) and install the `dt~angular` typings. from there you should start getting intellisense, go to definition and possibly error checking.

Code should then pick this up (if not just reload the editor). You should then start getting intellisense. If you want to tweak it more, I would suggest looking into `jsconfig.json` files: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: Thank you. I installed the typings-installer but I am not sure how to use it. After typing `F1 > Typings Installer: Typings`, it says "enter typings name".

I then type "dt~angular" and it says "no typings found for 'dt~angular".

Comment: Try it without the `dt~` portion

Answer (score 0):

You can get general purpose typing information pulled by enabling Synthetic Default Imports in Visual Studio Code.

It lets you get Intellisense either from TypeScript type definitions or by inferenced type information from the JSDoc of many popular repositories.

Here is a [tutorial](https://blog.tallan.com/2017/03/02/synthetic-type-inference-in-javascript/) for how to get things set up.